# How to read columns and rows from an Excel file with python?

Tags: python, csv

I saved some data generated by a python code. They were saved in Excel format (`.csv`) using the commands

```
with open(path + '/data_Sevol.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
     fieldnames = ['Sevol']
     writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
     writer.writeheader()
     for i in range(len(Sevol)):
         writer.writerow({'Sevol': Sevol[i]})
```

and has the following format (100 rows × 1 columns):

[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

[[6, 7, 8, 9, 1]]

[[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]

...

[[7, 8, 9, 1, 2]]

In another notebook in jupyter I called this file

`data_Sevol = pd.read_csv(path + str("\\") + str("data_Sevol.csv"))`

and it was read correctly. But I'm not sure how to call a particular row or column from it. When I do, for example, `data_Sevol[0]` or `data_Sevol[1]`, thinking that the program would return line 0 or line 1 of the file, jupyter prints the following error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [27], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 data_robs[0]

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:3505, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3503 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3504     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3505 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3506 if is_integer(indexer):
   3507     indexer = [indexer]

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3623, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:
-> 3623     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3624 except TypeError:
   3625     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3626     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3627     #  the TypeError.
   3628     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

After loading the file, you can print the top 5 rows and see column name and row names:

```
data_Sevol.head()
```

After that, if you want to access any row or column by its name you can make use of below code:

```
data_Sevol.loc[row_name, col_name]
```

and in case you want to access it using row number or column number, make use of below code:

```
data_Sevol.iloc[row_num, col_num]
```

For reference, please refer to this link:
https://www.shanelynn.ie/pandas-iloc-loc-select-rows-and-columns-dataframe/

Comment: Thanks! It really worked. But with another file that I had saved by someone else, the ```data[0]``` form worked. Could it be the way I saved the data? Do you know if there is a better way?

Comment: It may work if your column name is `0`